# Get bitmap from video InputStream in android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am facing a problem while retrieving a `Bitmap` from a video `InputStream`. I don't have a video file, only the video `InputStream`.

I use this line of code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

...but it returns a null `Bitmap`. What am I doing wrong?

this is my code to get InputStream

```
public static InputStream decryptInputStream(File encryptedFile) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES"));
    return new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(encryptedFile), cipher);
}
```

Comment: Post your code...maybe you might have not initialized properly

Comment: @Akshay i have posted my code..

Comment: I'm pretty sure bitmapfactory expects the InputStream to come from a Bitmap, not a video. I think you need to find a way to extract individual frames from the inputstream first

Comment: is it in a try/catch block?

Comment: @reden , I think you are right. but how can i get frames from input stream?

Comment: @Akshay yes it is.

Comment: Check the documentation for the video format. Parse the data until you hit whatever indicates the end of a frame, then grab those bytes and make an image ouf of them. I haven't done it myself, but you should find the information you need by searching a bit.